# Нужна ли запятая перед «и»? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, и

*Нам дана возможность выбора(,) и выбирать нужно не между двух, а из трёх.*

Answer (score 2):

***Нам** дана возможность выбора **и** выбирать нужно не между двух, а из трёх.*

Из справочника по русскому языку (Д. Э. Розенталь, [стр. 406](https://kak-pishetsya.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Spravochnik-po-russkomu-yazyku.-Ofografiya-i-punktuatsiya.-D.E.-Rozental.pdf)   ):

> **2.** Перед союзами *и, да* (в значении *и*), *или, либо* запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо *общим элементом*.
> **1)** Общим может быть *второстепенный член* предложения: <...> ***Тут** так же, как и в зале, окна были раскрыты настежь и пахло тополем* (Ч.); <...> ***У него** осунулось лицо и отяжелели веки* (М. Г.)...

Я специально выбрала из правила только похожие предложения.
Если автор считает дополнение, выраженное местоимением "нам" (кому?), общим членом и подразумевает, что оно относится к каждой части предложения (***Нам** дана возможность выбора. **Нам** выбирать нужно не между двух, а из трёх*), то запятая не ставится.
Наличие общего второстепенного члена тесно связывает такие предложения в одно целое.

Само предложение мне кажется не совсем удачным. Я бы написала так:
*Нам дана возможность выбора, но выбирать приходится не между двух, а из трёх.*

Answer (score 0):

Да, запятая нужна. Это сложносочиненное предложение, соединенное союзом «и», при отсутствии трех причин не ставить запятую: когда есть общее сочетание, к которому относятся части сложного предложения; когда части сложносочиненного вопросительные, побудительные или восклицательные; когда части сложносочиненного являются односоставными.
Может показаться, что предложения односоставные, но нет: в первом предложении подлежащее ‟возможность”, а сказуемое ‟дана”.